# Find the least costly path in a polygon

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, polygon, graph-algorithm

I am trying to find a path inside a polygon considering its cost.

In my specific case, I have a character that should only go relatively straight, that is it should not differ by more than a few degrees from moving to north, east, south or west.

Ideally, I would assign a cost that increases with deviation. I’d assume this is a graph theory related problem, but I have no idea how to do this in a polygon…

The red dashed path in the illustration is what regular algorithms produce; the green is about what I want. **EDIT:** I messed up the picture a little; to clarify: The red path is meant to be the shortest possible path inside the polygon and I do want the green path to be the shortest that is possible given the angle constraint.

[image: Illustration]

*(To clarify, if my polygon looked something like* `(1)`, *I would want the path to be something like* `(2)`, *not simply a straight line between the points)*

```
(1)   ,-------------------+      (2)   ,-------------------+
     /               (B)  |           /               (B)  |
    /                     |          /                /    |
+--+                      |  ->  +--+                /     |
|                       +-+      |                  /    +-+
| (A)                   |        | (A)-------------+     |
+-----------------------+        +-----------------------+
```

Comment: A* can probably be adapted to your angle restrictions

Comment: is your space discrete or continous?

Comment: @VikramBhat It’s continous and comes as either a set of points/vertices or triangularized

Comment: @sp2danny A*/Dijkstra’s algorithm do look promising, but I’m not sure how to adapt them to a polygon, especially as there are no discrete nodes – I suppose I could use the polygon’s vertices as nodes, but since the ideal path doesn’t necessarily follow the edges, I don’t think that would work...

Answer (score 1):

This is really more of a comment, but I cannot comment since it requires 50 reputation... Otoh, I don't think there is satisfactory answer to this question, since it is not welldefined. But +1 for an interesting question :-)

The algorithm giving the red dashed line starts from the straight line between start and end point of your path (which isn't entirely inside the polygon.) You then slide along an edge of the polygon until you hit a corner and take that as your new starting point. (Note that the red dashed line you have drawn isn't really the shortest path.) Now your green line is basically the red line where you replaced pieces you don't like (wrong angle) with path that are longer but for some reason better (nice angles.) And that's also what gives you the "correct" answer to your example below. Just start from a straight line from (A) to (B), this is the shortest path and lies inside your polygon. Now replace this line by pieces with more favorable angles. (This may force you to take many turns in general...)

Just some thoughts.

Comment: Again I cannot comment on other Answers so I'll comment on my own instead... John Doe's first answer is great if you have a more complicated situation than the one you described (e.g. obstacles of all shapes inside your polygon.) For a simple polygon John Doe's second answer is basically the same as mine, except he prefers taking random paths instead of my deterministic approach :-)

Comment: Thanks for your input! What do you mean by “not welldefined”?

Comment: That's mathematicians speak for you were not very precise in specifying the type of path you are looking for. In particular I was a bit confused by (1) the red path is not actually the shortest and that's what I thought you were looking for, and (2) the horizontal part of the green path extends past the corner on the left, this makes it slightly longer than neccessary. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Oh, you’re right, I messed up the picture... The red path was meant to be the shortest path inside the polygon and I do want the green path to be the shortest that is possible given the angle constraint :)

Answer (score 1):

Run a [Rapidly exploring random tree algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidly_exploring_random_tree) but restrict the exploration direction within a few degree of directions parallel to an axis, and by choosing a large incremental distance to keep the number of turnings low. Basically add any heuristics at your wish.

[Rapidly-Exploring Random Trees: A New Tool for Path Planning](http://msl.cs.uiuc.edu/~lavalle/papers/Lav98c.pdf) is a seminal paper on Rapidly exploring random trees.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add another answer here since it's vastly different than my other one. Starting from the result of regular path finding algorithms, run a stochastic optimization to maximize a fitness function that describes the "relatively straightness" (and shortness and other metrics if you so wish) of a path by adding vertices, moving vertices and deleting vertices in a path, while still keeping the path valid.

Common stochastic optimization methods include [Simulated Annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing).